# How to use DataTemplates to support inheritance with ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox, its data source is an observable array of some objects. These objects all are derived from a base class.

I am trying to give each instance of the array a certain data template to handle its differences with other instances.

```
abstract class Base
{
    public string a {get; set;};
}
class sub1 : Base
{
    public string prop1 {get; set;};
}
class sub2 : Base
{
    public string prop2 {get; set;};
}
```

If the array contains two instances, one is sub1, the other sub2, the list box should display for the first the two properties a and prop1, and for the second instance a and prop2.

Please advise,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Sub1Template { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Sub2Template { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is sub1) { return Sub1Template; }
        if (item is sub2) { return Sub2Template; }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateForSub1">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding a}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding prop1}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateForSub2">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding a}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding prop2}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <my:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MySelector"
                               Sub1Template="{StaticResource TemplateForSub1}"
                               Sub2Template="{StaticResource TemplateForSub2}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollectionSomewhere}"
             ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MySelector}" />
</UserControl>
```

That should get you started.

**Update:** You can certainly use `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ...}" ...>` to select a data template strictly based on the item type. It may be simpler to do so in a number of cases. A `DataTemplateSelector` can offer some flexibility that `DataType=` cannot, such as changing a template based on a value inside a class, or the results of a method call, etc. Choose whichever one works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a template for each of the types you want to display. Try something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyArray}">
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:sub1}">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding a}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding prop1}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:sub2}">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding a}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding prop2}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

MyArray is the array containing your instances.
local is the namespace for your classes sub1 and sub2

Comment: Your code does not compile, and is conceptually wrong. Please correct or delete your answer immediately.

Comment: For more than one `DataTemplate`, the data templates should be provided as resources rather than directly in the `ItemTemplate` property. Please adapt your answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I had a nightmare with copy and paste and then accidentally clicked save. I have updated my code to show the correct answer.

Comment: You really don't need `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a TextBlock, do you?